# ComboBox.store.loadData can't load single-item array

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, loaddata

I am using ExtJS 3.4 .
I have a structure with data for combobox like this:

```
var a = [[1,"text1"],[2,"text2"]]
```

I load it like this:

```
ComboBox.store.loadData(a);
```

But when I have only 1 item in the array

```
var a = [[1,"text1"]]
```

then it doesn't load at all. I've read that:

> an Array : Arrays will be converted to a Ext.data.ArrayStore
>   internally, automatically generating field names to work with all data
>   components. 1-dimensional array : (e.g., ['Foo','Bar']) A
>   1-dimensional array will automatically be expanded (each array item
>   will be used for both the combo valueField and displayField)
>   2-dimensional array : (e.g., [['f','Foo'],['b','Bar']]) For a
>   multi-dimensional array, the value in index 0 of each item will be
>   assumed to be the combo valueField, while the value at index 1 is
>   assumed to be the combo displayField.

But that doesn't explain how do I load an array with one element. Or whatever, it shouldn't be necessary an array, the point is to load only one item. I've tried loading this:
Code:

```
[{id:1,text:"text1"}]
[[{id:1,text:"text1"}]]
{id:1,text:"text1"}
```

Even creating a custom ArrayStore:

```
Code:
 var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                            autoDestroy: true,
                            storeId: 'Store1',
                            idProperty:"id",
                            fields: ["id","text"]);
ComboBox.store = store;
ComobBox.store.loadData([{id:1,text:"text1"}]);
```

But everything loads incorrectly  . Either the combobox is empty, or it displays id instead of text.

I can see that if I lazily init the combo:
Code:

```
{"xtype":"combo","width":250,"fieldLabel":"my combo","value":31029,"forceSelection":true,"hiddenName":"ComboHiddenName","minChars":1,"triggerAction":"all","store":[[31029,"gdfs"]]}
```

then the array with one item will load successfully. At which properties of ComboBox.store should I look to configure them properly for a single-item array to be loaded correctly using loadData method?

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: why would you want a store with one record?

Comment: @Jaitsu how do load one item to a combobox otherwise, without using a store?

Comment: that's exactly my point, why would you ever have a combo box that only has one option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ComboBox.valueField = "id";
ComboBox.displayField = "text";
ComboBox.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({autoDestroy: true, fields: ["id", "text"]});
```

Answer (score 1):

`ComboBox.store.loadData(var a);` would not work for any data. It would raise exception `Unexpected token var`. Instead one should use `ComboBox.store.loadData(a);` without `var`

Comment: ofcourse it won't, that's my misspelling, but it's not a correct answer

Comment: In extjs 3.3.1 your example works just fine. I've checked by invoking code var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                            autoDestroy: true,
                            storeId: 'Store1',
                            idProperty:"id",
                            fields: ["id","text"]});
var cc = new Ext.form.ComboBox({"fieldLabel":"my","value":31029,"forceSelection":true,"hiddenName":"ComboHiddenName","minChars":1,"triggerAction":"all","store":[[31029,"gdfs"]]});
cc.render(Ext.getBody()); c.store.loadData([[1,'dgkj']]);
So, maybe, there are issues with your version of extjs.